# What is くん doing in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, particles

I have come across two sentences in a manga that is using くん in a way that I can't seem to find any information on, in both my books and online. I am guessing this may be some sort of slang, odd grammar or a compound of words/grammar that dictionaries don't seem to pick up on.

「おめーはちょくちょくうちの晩飯　食いに**くん**なー」

and

「てゆーか　なんで連れて**くん**だ？」

Slight edit: maybe this is some form of 来る？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I believe it's a contraction of `くる`.  Although the second example could possibly be a contraction of `連れていく` depending on the context.

Comment: So, you're saying なんで連れてくんだ means なんで連れて来るんだ, "why do you take (somebody) here?" and that it could also be なんで連れて行くんだ, "Why are you taking (someone)(somewhere)?" depending on the context, right?

Comment: @Chocolate:  Yes, that what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is two different things in your two sentences:

1. くる→くん (similar sound change to わからない→わかんない)
2. shortened form of 連れていく + んだ (のだ)

Comment: Why did you get downvoted?  Your answer is basically the same as mine...

Answer (score -1):

I think in regular Japanese it would be:

「おめーはちょくちょくうちの晩飯　食いにくるなー」

「というか、　なんで連れていくんだ？」

I don't think in the second sentence its くる, since the る　contracts to ん, if we were to reformulate the sentence it would be

「というか、なんで連れてくるだ？」

Which I think it's gramatically incorrect. Most probably this ん is the nominalizer の used in the pattern　のだ and abbreviated to んだ. At least that's the way I see it =)

Comment: 連れてくるんだ can be contracted to 連れてくんだ just as 何するんだよ!? can be contracted to 何すんだよ!?

Comment: See I didnt know that! Always nice learning a little everyday ^^